# How can see the difference between 8bit and 16 bit controller using a program

Tags: atmega, msp430

How can see the difference between 8bit and 16 bit controller using a program??say the difference between an atmega8 and msp430..Can i explain this using a program and show this using a program.

Comment: What is there to explain and what are you trying to show?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean like a Windows program can detect whether it's running on a 32-bit or x64 processor? Or do you mean some sort of C language directive to find the native data width? Anyway you'll need to clarify it to get any reasonable answer.

Comment: i want to show the programming capability difference of both

Comment: At compile time you already know the difference between an ATmega or an MSP, you can't compile the program otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your program in C you won't notice the difference. Say you write

```
i++;
```

where `i` is an integer. A 16-bit controller will do this in a single instruction, whereas the 8-bit controller will have to increment the LOB (Low Order Byte) first, and when there's an overflow increment the HOB (High Order Byte). That's the basic idea, and in its most simple form for a hypothetical controller it may look like this:

```
i         dw           ; define i as unsigned word (i.e. 16 bit)

inc16bit  ld    r0,i+1 ; load register 0 with low order byte
          inc   r0     ; increment low order byte
          st    r0,i+1 ; store the result
          brne  skip   ; don't increment high order byte if zero flag not set
          ld    r0,i   ; load register 0 with high order byte    
          inc   r0     ; increment high order byte
          st    r0,i   ; store the result
skip      ret          ; return from function
```

It's a bit more complex when you're dealing with signed integers. But at the C source code level all this is hidden.

If you're working at assembly level you'll have to do what I just described by hand. You won't be able to assign 1234 to an 8-bit register either, but it will do nicely on a 16-bit architecture. Your assembler will warn you when you try to assign 1234 to the 8-bit register.

Comment: can you explain me how it will differ in asm with a sample code

Comment: @ganes I added a program example.